# How do you solve a timetabling issue using taboo search on Python?

Tags: python, pseudocode, timetable, tabu-search

Essentially, I am unaware of how one could implement taboo search in order to create a Python program to create a timetabler. How would you go around this problem?

If the only criteria were for classes to be as balanced each day as possible (eg. no one day with more than two math classes), how would this look like in Python (code-wise and pseudocode-wise).

Thanks!

Comment: It probably helps to first write up the pseudo-code. Once this is done, it is probably easy to implement this in any programming language, including Python.

Comment: @DanielJunglas I'm not sure of how to write the pseudo-code though, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have pseudo code for plain local search (without tabus)? It is a good idea to start with that and add the aspect of tabus only later.

Comment: @DanielJunglas I know how to do a plain local search, but I don't know how to implement tabus. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check some documentation for Tabu search? For example, the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabu_search has pretty good explanations how to go from local search to tabu search. It also has a pseudo code example.